# bug in django template conditionals

Tags: django

Is this a django bug or am I doing something wrong? I have two problems.

1. When I put a block only when there are no posts, it inserts anyway.
2. When the block is inserted, it renders what is inside the block, in the block that I put, but also renders again as if it were some text in my html, in the same position as the block was inserted
3. The block is added anyway, containing posts or not, but block text is only displayed in html when there are posts.

because of a bug in the stack editor, I'm posting the code here too: https://pastebin.com/bTpGSRzN
images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwrq1.jpg
video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMewEz02EPs

in the first image, it adds the block being "else" at the same time that it adds the code and the text being in "if"

in the second, when there are really no posts, it adds the "else" block while rendering what is inside the block as a text in my container

fclass is to fix the footer if there are no posts, because the footer would be in the middle of the screen because there are no posts to occupy screen space

PS: inside the "posts.html" there is simply a for loop to create article elements containing the image and the information of each post, nothing more

```
<div class="container">
    {% if posts %}
        <h2 class="titlep mtop">Posts marcados com <span class="focotxt">{{ tag }}</span></h2>
        <p><small>{{ posts.paginator.count }} encontrados</small></p>
        {% include "posts.html" %}
        {% include "pagination_posts.html" %}
    {% else %}
        {% block fclass %} fixed-bottom {% endblock fclass %}
        <h2 class="titlep mtop">Nenhum post marcado com <span class="focotxt"> {{ tag|truncatechars:20 }}</span></h2>
        <p><a href="/blog/">Voltar para o Blog</a></p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

views.py

```
def tags_search(request, tags):
    template = 'blog/post_tags.html'
    tag = tags

    q_obj = Q()
    for name in [tag]:
        # iexact or icontains
        q_obj |= Q(tags__name__iexact=name)

    post_list = Post.objects.filter(q_obj)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 1)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'tag': tag, 'posts': posts, }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: So this is a "super"template that is subclassed? It is not really clear to me what the "context" is. How is this template part of the "app".

Comment: You are far too quick to ascribe things to bugs. According to you, not only does Django's template system have a bug, but so also does StackOverflow's rich text editor. I'm pretty sure neither of those are true.

Comment: The django for me seems like a bug, as for the stack, the html code had disappeared from the preview of the post, it appeared after I added text above the code

Comment: I think double rendering is coming from the line         {% include "posts.html" %}. I cant be sure as I dont know what inside that file.

Comment: if there are no posts, everything in the else block will be rendered. i.e.        {% block fclass %} fixed-bottom {% endblock fclass %}
        <h2 class="titlep mtop">Nenhum post marcado com <span class="focotxt"> {{ tag|truncatechars:20 }}</span></h2>
        <p><a href="/blog/">Voltar para o Blog</a></p> this would be rendered

Comment: also, what do you hope to achieve with the line         {% block fclass %} fixed-bottom {% endblock fclass %} ? What purpose does it serve??

Comment: the problem is that this is rendered even if the condition is true, and when it is false, in addition to executing the else block, it executes the text inside the fclass block as being a normal text inserted in the html

Comment: fclass is to fix the footer if there are no posts, because the footer would be in the middle of the screen because there are no posts to occupy screen space

Comment: Try printing the value of posts, if it evaluates to True or not. It might help shed some light. context = {'tag': tag, 'posts': posts, } print(posts)
    return render(request, template, context)

Comment: I did the same condition of the template, and it is coming out as expected. "if not posts" returns print associated with condition " print ("post false") "

Comment: You could remove the fblock and just use some css with `min-height` to make sure the footer is not in the middle of the screen. That will simplify things remove one potential problem.